# c++ Operator overloading,

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Whats wrong with my code shown below? please somebody throw some light. Thanks for your time !

```
    #include<iostream.h>
      using namespace std;

     struct mydata{
        int mx;
        mydata(int x = 0){}
        mydata operator+(const mydata& rhs){

                mydata temp(rhs);
                return temp;
        }
        operator int() const{ return mx; }
        operator double() const{ return mx; }
};


int main(){
        mydata d;
        mydata r = d + 5; // L1
        5 + d; // L2
        d + d; // L3
}
```

Comment: Could you remove the line numbers? It prevents people from compiling your example. Good example code though!

Comment: Should mydata( int x = 0 )-constructor do mx = x; ?

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>`? Are you using turbo c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (stated the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927604/c-operator-overloading/13927749#comment19200638_13927604)) is that compiler doesn't know which <kbd>+</kbd> you want to execute:

```
(double)d + 5
```

or

```
(int)d + 5
```

In order to resolve this ambiguoity, you should point the type conversion, or replace one of these operators by a named function:

```
    operator int() const{ return mx; }
    operator double() const{ return mx; }
```

If you want instead use d + mydata(5) you should write so, because the above variants are more likely to be applied

Answer (score 3):

First, you haven't stated what the problem is, but presumably you want an `operator+` that sums the `mx` values of two `mydata` objects:

```
mydata operator+(const mydata& rhs){
        return mydata (mx + rhs.mx);
}
```

Next, I would suggest making this a non-member function, so that the LHS and RHS get treated in the same way, fixing the problem in `L2`:

```
mydata operator+(const mydata& lhs, const mydata& rhs){
        return mydata (lhs.mx + rhs.mx);
}
```

Finally, you will have an ambiguous overload remaining, because the compiler cannot decide whether to use the built-in `operator+(int,int)` or your own `operator+(const mydata&, const mydata&)`. You can fix this by removing the cast operators `int()` and `double()`.

See demo [here](http://ideone.com/LmLeDG).

Comment: I can only approve of removing the cast operators :6

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a few non-member operator+ to enable `operator+` with different data type:

```
mydata operator+(const mydata& lhs, const mydata& rhs){
        return mydata (lhs.mx + rhs.mx);
}
mydata operator+(int mx, const mydata& rhs){
        return mydata (rhs.mx+mx);
}

mydata operator+(const mydata& lhs, int mx){
        return mydata(lhs.mx+mx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do 5 + d. 5 can not be converted to class object like this. For this you need to get the operator +  definition out of the class method. (in my knowledge preferably friend).

Comment: That is what was suggested in the answer by @juanchopanza with bare minimum code sample

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. It was later edited, to add this point. The first I saw it wasn't there.

Comment: Thank you all for the response !